# I can't recognize anything in this sentence

Tags: grammar, words

For context, see this document: 
https://www.docdroid.net/uHP3GDN/img-20170622-0001-new.pdf.html

Counted upwards from the bottom of the text, it is sentence 4.
でも、学校は6時**からって** **なってますが** 、仕事のほうは大丈夫ですか。

So, contentwise, I guess his boss asks him wether it will be okay if this seminar starts at 6 o clock. 
But I'm so irritated by the morphology of the words in bold and their placement in the sentence, I can't tell what they do grammarwise Oo

First, からって. I just learned about て and って being able to mark a quote in place of と.
Whatever, in this case って in からって is a quotation marker, right?
Well, then what for christs sakke is なってますが ? Oo 
I once learned that まして is possible to be more polite, but I've NEVER before encountered て form followed by ます Oo 
Furthermore, I don't know what this て form in なってますが　does grammarwise. 
I can't see it acting as a connector here, but I can't see how it should be a second quotation either Oo

Finally, I also have problems with the meaning of 仕事のほう. I currently would say its something along the lines of "the field of work". At least I can't find any other translation on jisho for ほう　which would be suitable in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> でも、学校は6時**からって なってますが**、仕事のほうは大丈夫ですか。

There are some ommiting phrases and a colloquialism in the given sentence.
Let's look at them one by one.

- でも、 *However/But/Though/Although*
- 学校は６時**からって** is 学校は６時**から**（始{はじ}まる）**と**
  *the seminar/class/(school) starts at six*
  The change from からと to からって is a colloquialism, which is said by Philippe in the comment.
- なってます　is （規則｛きそく｝/規程｛きてい｝で）なっています or （パンプレットに）書｛か｝いてあります
  *determined by the rules*, *written in the brochure* or *according to the brochure*
- が、　が is like けど, which often connects contrasting clauses, but in this case, it can just connect two clauses that do not contrast.
- 仕事**の方**は is 仕事**について**は　*as for your job*
- 大丈夫ですか is (勤務｛きんむ｝時間帯｛じかんたい｝は）大丈夫ですか or 勤務｛きんむ｝時間帯｛じかんたい｝は学校｛がっこう｝の授業｛じゅぎょう｝時間帯｛じかんたい｝と重｛かさ｝なりませんか
  *is the working hours / working time zone OK?*

As for the whole meaning of the given sentence is like:

> *However, as for your job, is the working hours OK because the seminar starts at six according to the brochure?*

Comment: 学校は６時からって is supposed to be something like 学校は６時からって言う ?

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira: If it was written out in full grammatical patterns, it would be 学校は6時からとなっていますが, and the と became って in colloquial speech.

Comment: @Philippe I see, I'm not used to the となる pattern, i'm used to になる, I have to look for it

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira: You'll get used to it quickly, I'm sure. It comes up all the time!

Comment: Sry but I don't understand this segment:
なってます　is （規則/規程で）なっています or （パンプレットに）書いてあります

How should I know that I'm expected to make such huge extrapolations? Oo
If the "rule/regulation" semantics is carried by the なってます　phrase, why is there no preceding ことに? ...ことになっている　can express that something has been/is set up as a rule, according to the grammar section in my textbook. There was no case displayed where ことに is omitted :(. 
...に なる on the other hand expresses that something changes its state. 
But okay, there isn't even a に left...^^

Comment: @mackygoo Glad to be of assistance. I was getting ready to write an answer, but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: @Narktor Japanese, with its lack of explicit subjects and other elliptical phrasings, is highly contextual, and the extrapolations aren't really "huge" in that respect. mackygoo was being very thorough in explaining, but it's more a matter of acquiring a feel for these expressions through exposure and practice. In this specific case, the と (colloquialized to って) is favored over に simply because the state isn't changing, it's already been set from the point of view of people reading the brochure. It's simply the equivalent of "*this says* it starts at 6."

Comment: Yeah I know, this shouldnt criticize mackygoos answer, I just wanted to know if there's any explicit reference points in the text where these extrapolations refer to. The brochure for example isnt mentioned anywhere in the text. The only thing is "これです" in line 10, where I must say though that I wasnt sure wether it points "forward", meaning これ refers to what he says afterwards, or to something both dialoguepartners can perceive making it "deictic". 
Im used to making extrapolations from context, but its pretty hard to do so if the context is so weakly represented in the maintext, I think.

Comment: @Narktor:  If we see or hear the phrase (1), we usually guess the meaning of it may be like (6-1) or (6-2). I'm not talking about huge extrapolations, but it's a very simple guessing process.  (1)「６時からってなってます」→ (2)「６時からってなっています」→ (3)「６時からだとなっています」→ (4)「６時からだと（どこかで）なっている」→ (5-1)「６時からだと（どこかで）決まっている」or  (5-2)「６時からだと（どこかに）書いてある」→ (6-1)「６時からだと（規則/規定などで）決まっている」or  (6-2)「６時からだと（パンフレットなどに）書いてある」

Comment: @mackygoo Thanks! This gave me a little more insight into the nuts and bolts of doing this :D 

One question came up about your examples:
「６時からだと（規則/規定などで）決まっている」
「６時からだと（パンフレットなどに）

などに　and などで
Is it just a rule that should be accepted that に is used with 書く when giving local information, and で when 決まる　is coupled with local information? Or is there more to it?

Comment: @Narktor: The combination of などで and 決まる ( or などに and 書く) is one thing, and where we get local information is another. As for the two sets of combination, they are quite natural. 規則で決まる and パンフレットに書く are natural expressions, and the added など (etc.) would not change the being natural. As for the place where local information is given, I'm not sure, but as for the information such as the starting time of the class is possibly got from such media.